# Query function bringing blank value where it should be a Not Set value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am trying to query data from another tab but when i use the query formula it brings blank values and in the original table has a Not Set value. How can I make it to bring the original value?

This is an example sheet from the image

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=143560317)

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the optional header parameter 1:

```
=QUERY(A1:A,"select *",1)
```

It looks like QUERY is getting confused and is thinking that the 'Not Sets' are part of the header and is concatenating them.

Comment: True, it was missing to specify the header, thanks a lot, and now what is happening is that it brings blank values, how could I make it to bring the not set value in the query as in the original?

Comment: Try =arrayformula(query(to_text(A1:A),"select *",1)) - this is probably happening because QUERY only accepts the majority data type in a column and you have more dates than 'Not sets'

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY({A1:A}, "where Col1 is not null", 1)
```